# PyFlink Error/Exception: "Hive Table doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node PythonGroupAggregate"

Tags: exception, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

Using Flink 1.13.1 and a pyFlink and a user-defined table aggregate function (UDTAGG) with Hive tables as source and sinks, I've been encountering an error:

```
pyflink.util.exceptions.TableException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException:
 Table sink 'myhive.mydb.flink_tmp_model' doesn't support consuming update changes 
 which is produced by node PythonGroupAggregate
```

This is the SQL CREATE TABLE for the sink

```sql
table_env.execute_sql(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flink_tmp_model (
        run_id STRING,
        model_blob BINARY,
        roc_auc FLOAT
    )  PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING) STORED AS parquet TBLPROPERTIES (
        'sink.partition-commit.delay'='1 s',
        'sink.partition-commit.policy.kind'='success-file'
    )
"""
)
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you are executing a streaming query that is doing some sort of aggregation that requires updating previously emitted results. The parquet/hive sink does not support this -- once results are written, they are final.

One solution would be to execute the query in batch mode. Another would be to use a sink (or a format) that can handle updates. Or modify the query so that it only produces final results -- e.g., a time-windowed aggregation rather than an unbounded one.